# Multiply certain columns in csv files

Tags: pandas, shell, csv, awk

I have multiple large csv Files in which certain columns in my case where 0 is the first:

```
1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28,31,34,37,40,43,46,49
```

should be multiplied with -1.

I want to flip the sign of the numbers of those columns and make all + to - and the other way round. The file should then be saved. Is this possible with a shell script in linux? Maybe with awk or pandas or something similar?

Short Example:

```
-2,-4,-5, 8, 5, 7
```

should be

```
2, 4 ,5, -8,-5,-7
```

Edit: My Efforts so far are

```
import pandas as pd

myfile = open("anyfile.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(myfile, header=None)

#print(df, end="\n\n")

df[1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28,31,34,37,40,43,46,49] *= -1

#print(df)
```

How can i save that result to a new csv. Is it possible to automate this via shellscript?

Comment: On SO we do encourage all users to post their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so please do so and  let us know then.

Comment: Try something like this: `awk -F "," '{print $1*-1","$2*-1}' file.csv`

Comment: To save pandas `df`  you can use: `df.to_csv('outputfile.csv')`

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following. I am considering that you want to change sign for all columns and you want your output in comma separator format.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i*-1}} 1'  Input_file
```

OR(as per James sir's nice suggestion):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=-$i}}} 1'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Use awk:

```
columns="1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28,31,34,37,40,43,46,49"

awk -v f="$columns" '
    BEGIN{ FS=OFS=","; n=split(f,cols,",") }
    { for(i=1; i<=n; i++) $(cols[i]+1)=-1*$(cols[i]+1) }1
' file.csv
```

Where:

- a list of column numbers is specified as a variable `f` in awk and then split into an array called `cols`
- then you can loop through this array and find the column numbers by `$(cols[i]+1)`, and then do the math.

I assumed all columns are numbers and without embedded `,` in the fields.

Comment: `for(i=1; i<=n; i++) $(cols[i]+1)=-1*$(cols[i]+1)` = `for (i in cols) $(cols[i]+1)*=-1`

Answer (score 0):

Always add a `-` and remove `--`. Handle spaces.

```
echo "-2,-4,-5, 8, 5, 7" | sed -r 's/ //g;s/(^|,)/& -/g;s/--//g;s/^ //'
```